# Conditional style with a prop as a background-image url?

Tags: css, vue.js

So I know that it's possible to set a class conditionally in Vue, I was wondering if it's possible to set a style itself conditionally, inline? I don't see an example in the documentation.

The reason I want it to be inline is because the URL for a background-image is passed to the component as a prop, so it needs to be inside of a `:style="{ }"` tag, however if that image is not passed I want to show a gradient background within the `background-image` tag.

Something like this, but obviously this syntax is wrong:

```
:style="{ heroImage ? backgroundImage: 'url(' + heroImage + ')' : backgroundImage: linear-gradient(direction, $blue2, $purple2) }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as

```
:style="[heroImage ? {backgroundImage: 'url(' + heroImage + ')'} : {backgroundImage: linear-gradient(direction, $blue2, $purple2)}]"
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    heroImage: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300',
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style="height:500px;width:500px" :style="[heroImage ? {backgroundImage: 'url(' + heroImage + ')'} : {backgroundImage: linear-gradient(direction, $blue2, $purple2)}]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked but I needed to tweak it like so: `:style="[heroImage ? { 'backgroundImage': 'url(' + heroImage + ')' } : { backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(#000, #FFF)' } ]"`